# Adding information extracted from a spreadsheet onto a site

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script running on a site that is giving me an error: Service error: SitesApp: entry must have a plain-text, non-empty title (line 16)

```
function parseNews() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY_SPREADSHEET_KEY");
  var SourcePage = SS.setActiveSheet(SS.getSheetByName("Current"));
  var TargetPage = SS.setActiveSheet(SS.getSheetByName("Archive"));
  var TotalRows = SourcePage.getLastRow();
  var RowCount;
  var pages = SitesApp.getSite('mydomain.co.uk','home').getChildren();
  Logger.log(pages.length);
  for (RowCount=1;RowCount++;RowCount <= TotalRows){
    var titleText = SourcePage.getRange(RowCount,2).getValue();
    var urlText = SourcePage.getRange(RowCount,3).getValue();
    var postType = SourcePage.getRange(RowCount,4).getValue();
    var lineEntry = ('<div>'+titleText+'<THEREISANAHREFHERE="'+urlText+'">'+urlText+'</A></div>');
    Logger.log(lineEntry);
    Logger.log(pages[1].getTitle());
    var page = pages[1].setHtmlContent(lineEntry);
    Logger.log(page);
  }
}
```

Line 16 is the 'var page = pages[1].setHtmlContent(lineEntry);

Log output is:

```
2.0
<div>The new Samsung Galaxy S III Android Smartphone<A HREF="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-17935684">http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-17935684</A></div>
```

and when debugged, page is 'undefined'

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Apologies if the formatting is poor, It looked fine under preview! (Ubuntu 12.04+Chrome)

Cheers,

Sladey

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you've found a page that somehow doesn't have a title, and when trying to update it with setHtmlContent() an error is being thrown about the missing title. Try checking to make sure the page has a title before you try to modify it's contents.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the suggestion. On the document list, there was a document entitled '[Untitled]' I have removed that but I'm now getting  the same error!

Comment: To clarify, I believe there is a page in your Google Site that has no title.  It might be better to create a new page rather than update an existing one.